# Problem in working out a question related to diagonalisation of matrices.

Tags: diagonalization

**The question is** :

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ diagonalisable matrix whose eigen values are $1,3,6$ with some unknown multiplicity.Is the matrix $2A^2-A+23I$ diagonalisable?

I dont find any proper way to proceed.Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** :

I think if $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ then $2A^2-A+23I$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $2D^2-D+23I$.Isn't it?Hence $2A^2-A+23I$  becomes diagonalisable.

Comment: Hint. How do you compute a polynomial of a diagonal matrix? Then think about computing a polynomial of a diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: What is wrong in my edit?

Comment: I think you are right. The given eigenvalues are a red herring. You can answer your own question now - perhaps showing the argument for the similarity of the polynomials in the operators.